# How do you typecast a map in Go into a custom type?

Tags: go

I have a custom type defined:

```
type Thingy map[string]interface{}
```

and I have a function that is passed an empty interface argument:

```
func f(arg interface{})
```

What I'd like to do is be able to typecast arg into a variable of type Thingy.  I must be misunderstanding something fundamental about Go because I can't get this to work:

```
t, ok := arg.(Thingy)
```

`ok` always returns false there.  Any ideas?  Full example here: http://play.golang.org/p/TRZsX4v8-S

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/U16u6-msqA , or http://play.golang.org/p/UHyFyNP7Ll

Comment: @nos That's helpful-- I'm closer to the answer I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That's not a cast, but a type assertion.
2. You're not passing a `Thingy`, but a `map[string]interface{}`

It's important to understand that just because types look similar, that doesn't mean you can use them interchangeably.  This is most important when there are method sets.  A call to `x()` on two different types have to be distinguishable even if the underlying types are the same.

Comment: Agree map[string]interface{} != Thingy. Thingy is a new defined type.

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess my question is then, how can I convert from map[string]interface{} into a Thingy.

Comment: Aha I figured it out.  I need to do a type assertion to map[string]interface{} first, and then if that passes I can convert with Thingy(arg) as per @nos's comment above.  Thanks very much for the help.